# Understanding Python Classes - Adding or removing employees without writing new code

Tags: python, class, object, instance

I'm trying to get a better understanding of classes in python. (*Still new to OOP*)  I get the fundamentals of it like , objects, methods, attributes etc. The issue I'm having is understanding how I can allow someone using a theoretical application to create a new instance of a class. For example: Lets say I have an application that allows a company to add and remove employees from a list. How would the user be able to create or remove instances of class employee without having to write a new line of code. employee_1 = employee("Tim", 34), employee_2 = employee("Sarah", 27) ??

I've tried finding some more information online about this but to no avail. All the information I can find on classes just shows how I can create classes and objects as well as calling methods on those objects etc. The example I gave above is used quite often as a way of adding people to an employee class but for some reason I'm thinking that I should be able to create instances of the class from a applcation interface. Am I looking at classes the wrong way? Or is there something I'm missing? Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Consider `new_emp = Employee(input("Enter name:"), int(input("Enter age:")))`.  Then append that object to a list.

Answer (score 0):

> The example I gave above is used quite often as a way of adding people to an employee class but for some reason I'm thinking that I should be able to create instances of the class from a applcation interface. Am I looking at classes the wrong way? Or is there something I'm missing?

You're on the right track. You're missing the rest of the architecture and components of your application, which isn't necessarily in Python either.

A. Somewhere you have a user-facing interface (the front-end), where users fill in a form and hit save.

B. The data in the form is validated, and is sent to the backend code (your Python files) in an expected format (e.g., JSON: `{"firstName": "Robert", "lastName": "Lowe",...}`.
Somewhere in your backend, you have some code running that is listening and waiting for any incoming data. Once that data is received, it's passed to the class constructor, maybe in a for-loop, to create different employees:

```py
def create_users_from_data(data: [dict]):
    for el in data:
        new_employee = Employee(first_name=el["firstName"], ...)
        # do other stuff
```

C. Of course, the last piece would be that this information needs to be saved, and so after you created your employee instances, there should be a step to save the data in a database:

```py
        new_employee.save_to_database()
```

Step A is not necessary for step B. B. can obtain that data in a number of different ways, aside from a user-facing form.